# C - Terminating a process with signal()

Tags: c, linux, process, named-pipes

I have a server and a client. The client has the option to terminate the server.

For that im using:

```
void killServer()
{
    int server_p_id;
FILE *file;

file = fopen(SERVER_INFO, "r");
if(file == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\nErro ao abrir %s", SERVER_INFO);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

fscanf(file, "%d", &server_p_id);
fclose(file);

kill -9 -server_p_id;
unlink(SERVER_FIFO);
}

/* some code */

if (!strcasecmp("fim",buffer)) 
            {
                signal(SIGUSR1, killServer);
                break;
            }
```

The problem is that the process is not being terminated. Is this the right way to do it ?

EDIT: Current code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include "dict.h"

#define MAX 256

void killServer()
{
    int server_p_id;
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen(SERVER_INFO, "r");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nErro ao abrir %s", SERVER_INFO);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fscanf(file, "%d", &server_p_id);
    fclose(file);

    kill(server_p_id, SIGKILL);
    unlink(SERVER_FIFO);
}


int main()
{
    int s_fifo_fd;   /* identificador do FIFO do servidor */
    int c_fifo_fd;   /* identificador do FIFO deste cliente */
    pergunta_t perg; /* mensagem do "tipo" pergunta */
    resposta_t resp; /* mensagem do "tipo" resposta */
    char buffer[80]; /* para a leitura da palavra a traduzir */
    char c_fifo_fname[25]; /* nome do FIFO deste cliente */
    long fflags;
    int read_res;
    CLEAR;

    //Abrir fifo do servidor
    s_fifo_fd = open(SERVER_FIFO, O_WRONLY); /* bloqueante */
    if (s_fifo_fd == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "\nO servidor não está a correr\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    //Cria fifo para receber resposta do servidor
    perg.pid_cliente = getpid();
    sprintf(c_fifo_fname, CLIENT_FIFO, perg.pid_cliente);
    if (mkfifo(c_fifo_fname, 0777) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "\nErro no FIFO para a resposta (1)");
            close(s_fifo_fd);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    //Abre o fifo para receber a resposta do servidor
    c_fifo_fd = open(c_fifo_fname, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (c_fifo_fd == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "\nErro no FIFO para a resposta (2)\n");
            close(s_fifo_fd);
            unlink(c_fifo_fname);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    fflags = fcntl(c_fifo_fd, F_GETFL);
    fflags ^= O_NONBLOCK; /* inverte a semântica de bloqueio */
    fcntl(c_fifo_fd, F_SETFL, fflags); /* bloqueante = on */

    perg.palavra[TAM_MAX-1] = '\0';

    printf("\tIntroduza os comandos pretendidos\n\n");

    /* Ciclo Principal */

    while (1)   /* caso escreva "fim" o programa termina */
        {

            /* ---- a) OBTEM PERGUNTA ---- */
            printf("[ADMIN] ");
            scanf("%s",buffer);

            if (!strcasecmp("fim",buffer)) 
            {
                signal(SIGUSR1, killServer);
                break;
            }

            strncpy(perg.palavra,buffer,TAM_MAX-1); //copia a palavra lida do "buffer" para a "perg.palavra"

            /* ---- b) ENVIA A PERGUNTA ---- */
            write(s_fifo_fd, & perg, sizeof(perg));

            /* ---- c) OBTEM A RESPOSTA ---- */
            read_res = read(c_fifo_fd, & resp, sizeof(resp));
            if (read_res == sizeof(resp))
                printf("[SERVER] %s\n", resp.palavra);
            else
                printf("Sem resposta ou resposta incompreensivel[%d]\n",read_res);
        }

    close(c_fifo_fd);
    close(s_fifo_fd);
    unlink(c_fifo_fname);

    printf("Programa Terminou com Exito!");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant way of inlining shell code into C! How many warnings did you have to ignore to fail to spot the problem?

Comment: Did you try to compile this?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: `http://stackoverflow.com` also compiles...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Yes, no warnings or errors by gcc.

Comment: It should warn you that an expression has no effect, or something like that. (Edit:) I get at least `warning: pointer to a function used in arithmetic` and `warning: statement with no effect`. Maybe invest in a better compiler?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 13.04 with gcc 4.7.3 :/
It didnt "said" anything. Instead of `kill` what function should i use ?

Comment: Try [`man 2 kill`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) on your command line.

Comment: @xRed: Does that line **look** like valid/meaningful C?

Comment: @xRed I think they are talking about "kill -9 -server_p_id;" in the middle of your C code.  Typo or cut/paste error?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: It really doesnt, but has i said, compiler got 0 warnings so i tought it was ok. Will change code and post update. Thanks

Comment: @xRed: let's try it again with `-Wall -pedantic -ansi -Wstrict-prototypes`, just for fun. And then always use that from then on. And please indent your code decently before asking questions here. You're the ONE person asking, we are the *hundreds* reading it. Also, provide complete code if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kill` is a function pointer. Standard C does not allow pointer arithmetic on function pointers, though many compilers offer it as a (fairly meaningless) extension.

In short, your code isn't valid C.

<sub>However, the perfectly valid C code `kill(server_p_id, SIGKILL);` may well do what you want.</sub>