# How to stop a child process if not completed after a timeout

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I have a program that starts a child (`r.out`), and that child has a time limit.

I want to know how to stop running `r.out` after passing the time limit.

I am running the code on Linux.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TIME_LIMIT 1             //determine time limit

void my_function();         //supposed to include the submitted code
void alarm_handler(int);



int main()
{
    if (sigaction(SIGALRM, NULL, NULL) == -1)
        err(1, NULL);

    signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);    // assigning an alarm handler for SIGALRM

    alarm(TIME_LIMIT);  // install an alarm to be fired after TIME_LIMIT

    system("./r.out"); //Running the file

    alarm(0);
    return 0;
}


void alarm_handler(int sig)
{
    printf("%s" , "Time limit exceeded");
    //Here i want a code to stop the r.out file
}
```

Comment: Can you use threading? If so you can have `r.out` run in a thread and kill the thread after `n` seconds.

Comment: Send a `SIGKILL` to it.. But you better spawn it with `fork/exec` to have more control.

Comment: How to do it i need an example. I need it to be stopped from the c program.

Comment: The r.out will started when my program starts for example after 2 seconds of running it i want to close it using my c code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - Terminating a process with signal()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974229/c-terminating-a-process-with-signal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to kill the child, you need to know its pid.  You can get it if you start the program with `fork` and `exec` instead of `system`.

In addition to a signal handler for `SIGALRM`, set up one for `SIGCHLD` (received when a child process finishes) as well.  After calling `alarm` to set the timer, call `pause`.  This function will return when you get either of the two signals.

In the signal handlers you should only set a global flag.  Calling `printf` from within a signal handler can lead to undefined behavior.

After `pause` returns, check each of the two flags.  If the timeout flag is set, you can terminate the child with `kill`.

In either case, call `wait` to reap the child process's pid.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define TIME_LIMIT 1             //determine time limit

void alarm_handler(int);
void child_handler(int);

int timeout = 0;
int child_done = 0;

int main()
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork failed");
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        // child process
        execl("./r.out","r.out", NULL);
        perror("exec failed");
        _exit(1);
    }

    // set up the signal handlers after forking so the child doesn't inherit them

    signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
    signal(SIGCHLD, child_handler);

    alarm(TIME_LIMIT);  // install an alarm to be fired after TIME_LIMIT
    pause();

    if (timeout) {
        printf("alarm triggered\n");
        int result = waitpid(pid, NULL, WNOHANG);
        if (result == 0) {
            // child still running, so kill it
            printf("killing child\n");
            kill(pid, 9);
            wait(NULL);
        } else {
            printf("alarm triggered, but child finished normally\n");
        }
    } else if (child_done) {
        printf("child finished normally\n");
        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}


void child_handler(int sig)
{
    child_done = 1;
}

void alarm_handler(int sig)
{
    timeout = 1;
}
```

Comment: I think you are overdoing it. Install a dummy `SIGALRM` handler,  `wait` and if it returns `-1` with `EINTR`, then do `kill`. There is no need to deal with timeout, `pause` and `SIGCHLD`.

Comment: @user58697 on the machine I was testing on, `wait` would not return -1 with `EINTR` when the timer expired.  This method was necessary to ensure everything worked in both the expired case and the complete in time case.

Comment: This is very strange. `wait` behavior is perfectly well defined. What was that machine, may I wonder?

Comment: @user58697 I'm not in front of it at the moment, but I believe it was CentOS6 x64, 2.6 kernel.

Comment: what if i want to view the output of r.out before stopping it ?

Comment: it is working :D .. but i want to know how to get the output from r.out before stopping it . Thanks

Comment: Hi @user58697 , I'm trying to implement timeout as well and it is very hard to find questions and answers about that. Could you please reference me to a solution like the one you wrote?